# browserify is not working. gives undefined process.versions.node

Tags: javascript, browserify

I am trying to use browserify along with got & cheerio. I cant find any reference to got in the bundle.js. I also tried request instead of got, & I am facing the same problem.

```
nodejsMajorVersion = Number(process.versions.node.split('.')[0]);
```

In the above code within bundle.js, process.version has the value of undefined. If I manually set it to 12, the below error pops up.

```
Cannot read property 'Resolver' of undefined
    at Object.86.dns (bundle.js:19864)
```

I have tried with `npm install resolve`. As this was mentioned as a solution somewhere, but even this doesn't work. How do I make this to work?

Comment: maybe its that `process` won't work in the browser, odd error is like its bundling [dns](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_class_dns_resolver) which also won't work in the browser

Comment: but the purpose of browserify is to work on browser/cliet side, right? Then why this error?

Comment: No see the shims, ones with _empty.js wont work https://github.com/browserify/browserify/blob/e35437af10b9b628885102a6b8e0d1f39cb16c8d/lib/builtins.js

Comment: ..and process shim https://github.com/defunctzombie/node-process/blob/master/browser.js#L159

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browserify can package many modules for the browser, but not all. `got` does not work in the browser because it has to do things like dns lookups, which are impossible to do in the browser.

You would have to use a different http request library. The [node-fetch](https://npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) library will use the builtin Fetch APIs in web browsers, so it's a good option.

Comment: Thanks. I used a different flow & moved the operations to back-end.