# Browserify Error: Uncaught TypeError: Unable to determine current node version in bundle.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, browserify

so I recently installed browserify into my application, and I'm getting this error in the Chrome Dev console:

```
bundle.js:10677 Uncaught TypeError: Unable to determine current node version
    at versionIncluded (bundle.js:10677:9)
    at isCore (bundle.js:10694:28)
    at 71../core.json (bundle.js:15883:21)
    at o (bundle.js:1:265)
    at bundle.js:1:316
    at 67../lib/async (bundle.js:15523:14)
    at o (bundle.js:1:265)
    at bundle.js:1:316
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:6817:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:7158:4)
```

Here is the code in my app that is relevant to the error:

```
    var current = typeof nodeVersion === 'undefined'
        ? process.versions && process.versions.node
        : nodeVersion;

    if (typeof current !== 'string') {
        throw new TypeError(typeof nodeVersion === 'undefined' ? 'Unable to determine current node version' : 'If provided, a valid node version is required');
    }
```

So, basically it throws an error when it cannot get the the node version, it will not assign a value to current and it will throw an error later. I have Node v20.6.1, so I don't understand why nodeVersion is undefined or how to fix that. I'm guessing my app is supposed to pass that value when building the webpack but for some reason is not building it correctly. However, I am running the correct command to build the webpack:

```
 browserify scripts.js -o bundle.js
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

I have tried deleting the bundle.js and rebuilding it. I have also tried commenting out the error handling in general, but it needs the node version to assign a value to current for later.

Comment: I think you can't do this 
 var current = typeof nodeVersion === 'undefined'

Comment: What do you get with `console.log(process.versions);` and `console.log(process.versions.node);`, if you place them before `var current = ...``?

Comment: @FiddlingAway when I log console.log(process.versions) I get an empty object: {}. When I log console.log(process.versions.node) I get undefined.

Comment: Does [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62492311/browserify-is-not-working-gives-undefined-process-versions-node)?

Comment: Thanks, I was able to solve it with [this link](https://github.com/browserify/pbkdf2/pull/98). Apparently, I just had to write global.process.versions, but thanks because you set me on the correct path

Answer (score 0):

The answer was posted [here](https://github.com/browserify/pbkdf2/pull/98)

Apparently, browserify injects the variables when compiling so global and process are different. Global is the node and process is the browser process. I fixed the issue by changing process.versions and process.versions.node to global.process.versions and global.process.versions.node, respectively. Here is the new code:

```
  console.log(global.process.versions.node)
    var current = typeof nodeVersion === 'undefined'
        ? global.process.versions && global.process.versions.node
        : nodeVersion;
```